# How do I install py.test on a new MacBook ? pip fails

Tags: python, macos

Trying to use `pip install pytest` fails as pip has a problem with the package 6.  Here with a more detailed dump :

```
Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.

Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
...

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/gl/6qz_qqhn52g658r712r1rlnh0000gn/T/pip-XD54Hn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `venv`. You can also do this with `sudo` but there are security issues.

Comment: run as super user `sudo`

Comment: running via sudo makes no difference

Comment: Activate venv and try to install using pip e.g ENV/bin/pip install pytest. Check this will work.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged It's generally not necessary to run pip as super user! On Mac, you may mess up the system's python environment.

Comment: How did you install python and pip? Do you just use the one that came with MacOS, did you install it with homebrew or did you install a version from python.org?

Comment: You have messed up your system in the past (installing some package as the wrong user account). SO is not a good site to solve such problems.

Comment: I'd agree with @hop. For instance if you installed some packages with sudo pip install * and others without, you may end up in this state. My recommendation: Use a virtual env or set up a clean python environment.

Comment: This is a spanking new MacBook from the London Mac store.  pytest was the first thing I tried to install